# How to add multiple columns inside a single GroupProperty method of Nhibernate Projections Class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

I am using Visual Studio 2008. I am trying add multiple columns inside a single 
GroupProperty method of Nhibernate.Projections Class. But But I am failing to get the required output. I tried something like this.

```
    ICriteria Criteria = CreateCriteria("BaseCriteria");
projectionList.Add(Projections.GroupProperty(
            Projections.SqlFunction("concat", 
            NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("FirstName"), 
            Projections.Constant(' '), 
            Projections.Conditional(Expression.IsNotNull("LastName"), 
            Projections.Property("LastName"), Projections.Constant(String.Empty)))), "ClientName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, aside with `RowCount`, `Sum` and `GroupProperty` we can use `SqlGroupProjection`

```
var projectionList = Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.RowCount(), "RowCount")
    .Add(Projections.Sum("Price"), "Price")
    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("StatusId"), "StatusId")
    .Add(Projections.SqlGroupProjection(
            "LastName + ' ' + FirstName as ClientName",
            "LastName + ' ' + FirstName",
            new string[] {"ClientName"}, 
            new IType[] {NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String}) 
        , "ClientName")
```

The alias "ClientName" is repeated few times as an alias .. not sure which could be omitted, so prefer to use them all

And as shown here [NHibernate GroupBy and Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39908008/1679310)

That could be easily transformed into

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public virtual int RowCount { get; set; }
    public virtual int Price { get; set; } // type depends on SUM result
    public virtual int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

with

```
.SetProjection(projectionList )
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyDTO>())
```